# How to fix issues playing audio in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code in my viewcontroller. When I run, the audio doesn't play in the xcode simulator. Any advice on what I should do?

Also, I've saved anomaly.mp3 in the same directory (no sub-folders) as ViewController.m.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h> //before viewDidLoad    


NSError * error = nil;

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"anomaly"
                                     ofType:@"mp3"]];

AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                              initWithContentsOfURL:url
                              error:&error];
if (error){
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

NSLog(@"test");
[audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: And if you use a `NSError` in the `initWithContentOfURL:error:`? Is `url` `nil`?

Comment: Pass a `NSError` to the init of the `AVAudioPlayer`, Check if the audio player is set and check the passed error. It is never a good idea to pass nil for errors, because then you have no idea whats is going on.

Comment: I changed the code and pasted it above. Is this correct way to handle errors? If so, I'm not receiving an error in the console, but I am seeing the test from nslog...

Comment: You should check whether `audioPlayer == nil`, and only if it is, check the error. If it is not `nil`, the error is undefined and should be ignored. This is true of most Cocoa methods with a pass-by-reference `NSError` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the audio player's volume.  You can also check the results of the "play" function, to see if things worked correctly.  The play function implicitly calls prepareToPlay.  This function can fail out for a number of reasons, irritatingly without any error object or message...

```
NSError * error = nil;

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"anomaly"
                                     ofType:@"mp3"]];

AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                              initWithContentsOfURL:url
                              error:&error];
if (error){
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {

    audioPlayer.volume = 50;

    if([audioPlayer play]) NSLog(@"Should be playing");
    else NSLog(@"Something weird happened"); //usually related to unavailable hardware
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I incorporated this and "Should be playing" displays in the console. This is soo frustrating! Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a strong reference to the `audioPlayer` by declaring it as:

```
@property (nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

and then use `self.audioPlayer` wherever you have used `audioPlayer`.

The problem with your code is that because your `audioPlayer` is just a local variable to the method, it gets deallocated by ARC as soon as your method is completed. Keeping a strong reference to it will keep the `audioPlayer` object and memory and your sound will keep playing as long as you don't call

```
[self.audioPlayer stop];
```